# Why i can't see currentUser using firebase with react native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I can't signOut from firebase auth with email/password.

I'm using firebase (webApp) with react-native.

I can sign in, and store user in context - it works:

```
await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
setUser(firebase.auth().currentUser);
```

I can see my user in `user` state, but when I ask `firebase.auth().currentUser()` - it returns `null`. When I try `firebase.auth().signOut()` - I see `undefined` in console.

Someone know why it happens?

Comment: You should use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to respond to changes in auth state instead of depending on currentUser.  I've written a blog about this: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0

Comment: @DougStevenson , thank You! It helps.